# How to send a message to every user that is in same guild as bot?

Tags: discord.js

So basically I want to make bot able to send a message to every user that is in the same guild as a bot, I want to make it with a timeout, so I don't abuse Discord API.

Comment: Loop over the members and send each user a message...?

Comment: I think looping will cause discord abuse

Comment: You can store the members in an array and make the "loop" inside a `setInterval` callback. (Don't forget to increment the index.) By the way, I think even if you made a loop, Discord.js would place the requests in a queue until the rate limit expired.

Comment: Or can I make it with ``setTimeout`` so I have specific time between each message? I think that won't place the request in a queue.

Comment: Yes, `setTimeout` would also work.

Comment: I will test around with ``setTimeout``

Comment: You asked this multiple times by the way

Comment: "Multiple", only twice EDIT: in the last post I wasn't as clear

Comment: @D.Pardal couldn't find out how would it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending DM's using `setTimeout` would take forever so I filtered guilds with a channel named `auto-partnership`

```
setTimeout(() => {
let channel = client.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === "auto-partnership")
channel.forEach(channel => {
channel.send( "test")
})
}, 5000);
```

A bot is sending `test` message to every guild with a channel named `auto-partnership`